# Dynamic select2 options using api

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'll try to explain my problem as much as I can. I am trying to create, with `select2` plugin, a way for the user to write some letters and on each letter pressed a call to an API that gives the first 20 results given by that API.

So I have my HTML select :

```
<select name="filtre_products[]" class="form-control products-select2" multiple> 

</select>
```

And then my JS (it's commented) :

```
$(".products-select2").select2({ 
    width: '100%', 
    closeOnSelect: false,
    placeholder: '',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    query: function (query) {
        var data = {results: []}, i, j, s;
        if(query.term != null) {
            var ajax_r = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_products_recherche.php?limite=10&real_json=1&recherche='+query.term,
                success: function(data_a){
                    //Getting the data
                    data_a = JSON.parse(data_a);

                    //Looping through the each data and putting them inside a table
                    data_a.forEach( (e) => {
                        ajax_r.push(e);
                    });

                    //Filtering the data to get from it the id and the text to be used
                    ajax_r.forEach( (e) => {
                        var tmp = e.split('-');
                        var id = tmp[0];
                        var name = tmp[2];

                        data.results.push({value: id, text: name});
                    });

                    query.callback(data);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    //Sending the results to the function to modify the options as I please
    templateResult: formatResult
});
```

And this is the `formatResult` function I use :

```
function formatResult(d) {
    if(d.loading) {
        return d.text;
    } 

    // Creating an option of each id and text
    $d = $('<option/>').attr({ 'value': d.value }).text(d.text);

    return $d;
}
```

My problem is that `select2` is supposed to be creating the options dynamically upon initialization and thus actually creating `<li>` out of the options and adding to them dynamically id's and such. But in the way I'm creating it, it's putting the options INSIDE the `<li>` tags which is not what I want, I want it to treat it as dynamic options like he does without the query call.

Some doc sources for you guys, it shows a part of what I'm trying to do, but the example shows how to show results from what we write, I want it to show from the api upon each click, and of course having multiple select added : 
http://select2.github.io/select2/#data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read the documentation and found that the [ajax support](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) seems to fit your needs.

In your select2 options object, add an `ajax` object. Inside this `ajax` object :

- define the regular parameters for an ajax call (url, datatype, delay, etc.)
- in the data property, define function that returns the query parameters that should be added to the queryString
- in the processResults property, define a function that processes the data returned by the ajax call and returns an object containing a `results` array (just like the data object you're already building).

Then, you can reuse your templating function.

Here's a working snippet with a random API. Please note the query's term doesn't impact the returned data.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".products-select2").select2({
    width: '100%',
    closeOnSelect: false,
    placeholder: '',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (query) {
        // add any default query here
        return query;
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        // Tranforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
        var results = [];
        data.forEach(e => {
          results.push({ id: e.id, text: e.name });
        });

        return {
          results: results
        };
      },
    },
    templateResult: formatResult
  });
  
  function formatResult(d) {
    if(d.loading) {
        return d.text;
    } 

    // Creating an option of each id and text
    $d = $('<option/>').attr({ 'value': d.value }).text(d.text);

    return $d;
}

});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
      </script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

  <select name="filtre_products[]" class="form-control products-select2" multiple> 
  </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your ajax  success call,  do this  or similar.  i think you don't require such big code. below code snippet is from my working script.

```
success: function (data) {

                var dbSelect = $('#ddlItems'); // id for  Dropdown list
                dbSelect.empty();
                result = JSON.parse(data);
                // Parse result object and create your array collection in ajax_r object
                for (var i = 0; i < ajax_r.length; i++) {
                    dbSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: ajax_r.item[i].Value,
                        text: ajax_r.item[i].Text
                    }));
                }
            }
```